# `nicematrix`: \Block is not conforming to mono-column width constraint

Tags: nicematrix

The [`nicematrix` documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf) has this to say about "mono-column" blocks (blocks where the column span is 1):

> The natural width of the contents of these blocks is taken into account for the width of the current column.
> In the columns with a fixed width (columns `w{...}{...}`, `p{...}`, `b{...}`, `m{...}` and `X`), the content of the block is formatted as a paragraph of that width.

However, the following `NiceTabular` table:

```
   \begin{NiceTabular}{p{2cm}}[hvlines]
    \Block{2-1}{Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide} \\ \\
   \end{NiceTabular}
```

which is "mono-column", clearly produces a text block which has not been formatted as a paragraph.

[image: wide table]

Am I missing something, or is this feature nonfunctional?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! By use of the recent package version I can't reproduce your result. However, you are discover, that your text is to large that can be fit into block cell, consequently it will protrude out (above and below) of cell.  This may be considered as wrong use of `Block` or that it may be a bug.

Comment: Alas - the latest texlive on homebrew only includes 5.13. I assumed it would be up to date. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even the latest version of nicematrix ( 2022/03/11 v6.8) doesn't work too well.

You can add `cell-space-limits=6ex` to mitigate the problem, but it seems like a bug or information missing from the documentation.

[image: a]

Or by  adding more rows

```
    \begin{NiceTabular}{p{2cm}}[hvlines] 
    \Block{10-1}{Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide} \\
     \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
```

[image: b]

But as the OP points out

> One must remark that, by default, the commands \Blocks don’t create
> space. There is exception only for the blocks mono-row and the blocks
> mono-column as explained just below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{2cm}}[hvlines]
    \Block{2-1}{Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide} \\ \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\kant[2]


\begin{NiceTabular}{p{2cm}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=6ex] %% why cell-space-limits ???
    \Block{2-1}{Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide} \\ \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\kant[3]

    \begin{NiceTabular}{p{2cm}}[hvlines] 
    \Block{10-1}{Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide Wide} \\
     \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
    \end{NiceTabular}

    \kant[4]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I say in may comment ;-)

Comment: (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). As this time, the command `\Block` create vertical space only for mono-row blocks and horizontal space only for mono-column space...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that my version of `nicematrix` was not up to date. The version distributed with homebrew's `texlive` is not latest.